# do I have to clear std::vector before deleting it

Tags: c++

So far I have always been using vector::clear() before deleting the vector. But is it necessary? Isn't the vector::clear() function called in destructor anyway?

```
// Consider I have this vector
std::vector<uint32_t>* myVector = new std::vector<uint32_t>(50);

... // vector gets filled

myVector->clear();  // <-- redundant??
delete myVector;
myVector = nullptr;
```

Comment: That line is not the only thing that's redundant about your code!

Comment: Why on earth you're instantiating a `std::vector` using `new?`Do you have a particular reason to do so?

Comment: C++ is not Java.  There is no need to call `new` to create the vector.

Comment: And even if you do need to allocate a vector outside of the stack, please use smart pointers. `std::unique_ptr` is perfect for this. It's C++14, which your compiler should have by now. Try `auto x = std::make_unique<std::vector<uint32_t>>(50)`

Comment: This is just an example... I usually use pointer to std::vector when I have a function that returns it. Then I need to delete it eventually somewhere in my code.

Comment: Anyway I am no 'pro' c++ programmer, I'm still learning. I always try to keep the code efficient and without redundancy, but like I said I have still much to learn.

Comment: _"I usually use pointer to std::vector when I have a function that returns it. Then I need to delete it eventually somewhere in my code."_   There is almost never a good reason to do that either.  This may seem like it increases efficiency, but it doesn't.

Comment: And even then, you can still use a smart pointer for the return value, don't return a raw pointer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, all elements of the `std::vector` are destructed upon `std::vector` destruction anyway so using `clear` is redundant. You can see the documentation for [`std::vector::~vector` here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/~vector).

Additionally, dynamically allocating the vector as you have done in the question is typically unnecessary - just initialise via

```
std::vector<uint32_t> myVector;
//...
```

then `myVector` and all it's elements will be destructed when it goes out of scope.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no need to call `clear` manually. It may or may not get called internally when the vector is destroyed, but any objects in the vector will get destroyed one way or the other as the vector is destroyed.